# Excel VBA - Filter PivotTable based on cell value Error - Runtime 430 - Class Does Not Support Automation or does not support expected interface

Tags: excel, vba

I have a main Pivot Table on the worksheet 'Producer' where all my slicers are located (just location and month), and then a series of other pivots on other sheets (Producer1-5, Competitor, Competitor1-5).  The top half of my formula works and filters Producer1 based on the cell values B7 (which is the top value in the PivotTable on Producer).

However, using basically the same code for Competitor, it errors out, giving me a "Run-Time 430 Error - Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface" on line #8 and in debugger, top_competitor1 = Nothing when it errors out.

I want whatever value is in Cell B7 of the Competitor pivot (again the top value within the Pivot), to then filter the other Competitor1-5 pivots.   Any assistance would be appreciated.

Windows 10

Office 2013

```
   Sub Test2()
      Dim top_producer1 As Range
      Set top_producer1 = Worksheets("Producer").Range("B7")
        Worksheets("Producer1").PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("[Table3].[Producer_Parent].[Producer_Parent]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Table3].[Producer_Parent].&[" & top_producer1 & "]")
        
      Dim top_competitor1 As Range
      Set top_competitor1 = Worksheets("Competitor").Range("B7")
        Worksheets("Competitor1").PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("[Table5].[Competitor].[Competitor]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Table5].[Competitor].&[" & top_competitor1 & "]")
   End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that the pivot table on the `Competitor1` sheet is an OLAP pivot? Is it also named `PivotTable9` similar to the first code block?

Comment: Just double checked and yes, those are correct